# Explain the result of my C code. K&R "The C Prog language" Ex1-6

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Pl ref to my answer to Question 1-6 of K&R
Verify that the expression getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    int result;
    result=((c=getchar())!=EOF);
    while(result)
    {
        printf("\nValue of the exp %s\t is %d\n","getchar()!=EOF",result);
        putchar(c);
        result=((c=getchar())!=EOF);
    }
    printf("\nValue of the exp %s\t is %d\n","getchar()!=EOF",result);
}
```

Now pl see the output below when i enter the char 'w' the first time and 'Ctrl-D' the second time.

```
w

Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 1
w
Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 1

^D

Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 0
```

Why is the line

```
Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF is 1
```

being repeated twice?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text ... post text.

Comment: `result = (<stuff> != EOF)`.    The result is therefore a value of `0` if `<stuff>` equals `EOF` and `1` otherwise.    Also, the format string for the `printf()` in the loop has two format specifiers:  `%s` and `%d`.   Only one argument follows the format string.   The behaviour is therefore undefined, since `result` is `int` and doesn't match the format `%s`, and also because there is no argument to be printed using `%d`.

Comment: Because you pressed more than one key.  If you look real close then you can actually see the second character in the output.  Also try it with "hello".  This kind of buffered input was considered normal back in the 1970s when people still used teletypes.  They had different games back then :)

Comment: You don't need to do things from K&R. It is not even Ritchie actually, just Kernighan. He has a hobby of writing books (for money).

Comment: getcharing... getcharing... getcharing... getcharing...

Comment: You are lucky if you are not on linux (with canonocal input).

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the line `Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF is 1` being repeated twice ?

Because if your input is `w[Enter]` one `getchar()` reads the `'w'` and the next one reads the `'\n'`.

Comment: Hey..Thx..Forgot the newline

Answer (score 0):

Lets test this program with different inputs and lets observe the behavior.
before we proceed lets also include a `printf` statement to allow us understand what exactly is being read by `getchar()`

I'll modify the program like this now

```
    printf("\nValue of the exp %s\t is %d\n","getchar()!=EOF",result);
    putchar(c);
    printf("%d %d\n", c, c); // This should tell us what is being read
    result=((c=getchar())!=EOF);
```

Next a bit of manual stuff on `getchar`

> reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned
>   char cast to an int

This means from `stdin` `getchar` reads byte by byte until it encounters `'\n'` or `EOF` viz -1.

Lets get to testing now:

> Test 1:
>       `The usual input out put scenarios  with 'W' and ctrl+D`

```
W

Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 1
W87 87

Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 1

10 10

Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 0
```

in this case the contents in stdin are `'W\n'` thus 
the first `getchar` reads `W` and then the second `getchar` reads `'\n'`  while the third `getchar` reads `ctrl+d` which eventually sends `EOD` for termination.

> Test 2:
>       `Lets put these in a file and provide that as input to executable`

```
$ echo "W" > infile
$ cat infile
W
$
```

Observe that when we are doing the `cat infile` the prompt goes to next-line which means the input still contains '\n' eventually mean there should not be much change in the output when compared to previous case.

run should prove it

```
$ ./a.out < infile

Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 1
W87 87

Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 1

10 10

Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 0
$
```

> Test 3:
>       `get rid of the new - line`

by now we are reasonably sure that the culprit is `'\n'`, there is alternative to `echo` in linux called '`printf`' which does something similar to `echo` except without trailing next-line, we can make use of that to create an input file without next-line.

```
$ printf "W" > infile_wo_NL
$ cat infile_wo_NL
W$
```

observe this there is no `'\n'` so this should get rid of the second line in output.

```
$ ./a.out < infile_wo_NL
Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 1
W87 87

Value of the exp getchar()!=EOF  is 0
$
```